# HTML5+JQuery+JSON page is not able to fetch data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, html

Following Code is not displaying anything! Could someone help me to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flight Data</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
      url: 'http://www.flightradar24.com/zones/full_all.json',
      dataType: 'jsonp', // Choosing a JSON datatype          
      success: function(data) // Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
      {
          $('#flights').html(''); // Clear #flights div              
              for (var i=0; i<=10;i++) {          
                    $('#flights').append('Flight' + data[i] + '<br/>');                    
                    $('#flights').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;Reg D:' + data[i][0] + '<br/>');
                    $('#flights').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;Long:' + data[i][1] + '<br/>');
                    $('#flights').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;Lat:' + data[i][2] + '<br/>');
                    $('#flights').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;track:' + data[i][2] + '<br/>');                      
                  }
      }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Flight Data Loading...</h2>
 <div id="flights"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Only the "Flight Data Loading..." is being shown. The url is working from browser and JSON viewer.

Comment: You need to use JSONP in order to fetch data cross domain. Also you have and error in your javascript code, the last line should be }); because you are right now not closing the jquery right.

Comment: Thank you Chris; But the issue is persisting.

Comment: @RajaVaida Check the console for errors.

Comment: The `json` you're trying to receive is invalid respectively the headers aren't set correctly..

Comment: @enyce12, This is working for me now. The problem was with CORS.

Comment: @RajaVaida since you're using jsonp there shouldn't be a problem with CORS. Checkout the console of this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AZXAY/
It throws parse errors. The status is 200 so it's received but the document is not json.

Answer (score 0):

Change `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js` to `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have fixed it.

The server is sending JSON not JSONP. So there is noway I could access it directly.

I have implemented an interface which actually fetches the response from the url as a string and re-publish for my service.

My data will be slightly older while comparing with real time data published by the provider.